# Why did Reign of Fire end with the line "Well, here's to evolution."?

Tags: dialogue, reign-of-fire

The 2002 film Reign of Fire ends oddly with the line "Well, here's to evolution."

It seems out-of-place and unrelated to what I'd watched during the previous two hours. Was it just weak writing?

I assume they were trying to suggest that the humans won so they are more evolved than the dragons.

I'm not sure if there is a satisfying answer to my question, but on the chance there is I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The 2002 film Reign of Fire ends oddly with the line "Thank God for evolution" .. **Was it just weak writing?**

Pretty much, yeah. Though, I'd maybe more so describe it as "corny/cheesy" but that's just me...

> I assume they were trying to suggest that the humans won so they are more evolved than the dragons.

Yep, that's exactly what they were doing, essentially implying that there's a new world era where dragons aren't the rulers anymore and that humans now have dominion (or at the very least are able to fight for it).

And then, just as @A.bakker stated at the beginning of their response, it's also touching on Quinn's character change. However, it's definitely also about the dragons and plot, kind of like a double meaning.

Comment: Explanations on the DVs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

Quinn, who for the entirety of the movie (and presumably most of his life) has been a pessimist. But in the ending of the movie Alex notes that he is rather optimistic and happy (now that the dragons are gone, with him stating that even if they return they would just rebuild).

With Alex remarking that she thought optimism was against his nature. He replies that it is a recent development prompting her to say "Here's to evolution".

Her closing statement has nothing to do with the dragons or the plot, it's just a small joke about Quinn finally making (positive) changes in his life and "evolving" as a person.

Comment: Aside from the vaguely amusing juxtaposition of God and evolution, yes.